# elasticsearch configure hard disk size limit

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a Linux machine with 56GB of hard disk, but querying the max available space of ES shows only 28GB. We would like the ES to use more of the available space on the machine, but could not find the configuration for this. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have your index configured with one replica per shard?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch uses all the space that is available on your machine. However if this is a single machine in your cluster, then no copies of data will be created (as it does only make sense in a distributed environment to be failsafe friendly). So if you dont have more data, then no more is used.

It might make sense to talk about your setup and provide more information.